# CSRF Clarification (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, csrf

I just wanted to clarify my understanding of CSRF attacks in Rails.

Say we have a user Peter who is signed into **mainsite.com**. When he comes across a like button to "like" a page (implemented as a form), then **Rails generates an auth-token that is stored in the session (server-side) and also stored in the form itself**. Peter presses "like", and everything  works fine because the **tokens match**.

Now Peter, still signed in to mainsite.com, goes to **evilsite.com** and comes across a form that (unbeknownst to Peter) actually sends a request to mainsite.com/deleteAccount to delete Peter's account. When Peter runs into this form, **there is no auth-token**, so it does not match with the auth-token stored in Rails. Even if there were a hidden form to generate an auth-token, the **new token would be different** (hopefully) from the one already stored in Rails.

Are there any errors in my knowledge? Would love to know if there are any gaps in my understanding or what I could do to improve my understanding of CSRF attacks? Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The [Rails guides on CSRF](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures) cover this pretty well. You're pretty much correct about how it all works, except for:

> Even if there were a hidden form to generate an auth-token, the new token would be different (hopefully) from the one already stored in Rails.

The rails guides specify that:

> Note that cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities bypass all CSRF protections. XSS gives the attacker access to all elements on a page, so they can read the CSRF security token from a form or directly submit the form.

So basically, as long as the request comes in with a valid auth-token from the page, the default protection does not really help.